# localstack data does not persist during start and stop

Tags: localstack

i set the PERSISTENCE to true and DATA_DIR also exist,
i even confirmed that it was set by issuing "localstack config show" and there it is seen that the settings are indeed set.
i ran localstack with "localstack start -d" then i created an S3 bucket by "awslocal s3api create-bucket --bucket mybucket"
querying it after to confirm it has been created.
I tested the persistence by shuting down the docker image and restarting it.
i queried it again by "awslocal s3api list-buckets" but it doesnt looks like it was there and i need to recreate it.

how can i make localstack persist S3, SNS and database tables? we are trying to build our own local dev environment and it seems it is timed consuming to always recreate our data everytime.

Comment: same here. I tried with the suggested parameters but to no avail
https://docs.localstack.cloud/localstack/persistence-mechanism/

Answer (score 2):

Persistence works for LocalStock Pro users only
https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/6281

Comment: It actually works for the Community edition, too: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/6281#issuecomment-1668171870

Comment: Seconding Vasilen's comment above -- persistence is available in community edition, a pro subscription is not required.